# Want to retrieve random value from the response

Tags: jmeter

I have the following response payload and there are  4 `siteId` and I want to select any random `siteId` from it. This value of 4 can be change it will random, irrespective of it i want to select any random `siteId`.

**Response Value**

```
{
    "studyDTO": {
        "studyId": 191,
        "studyCode": null
    },
    "sites": [
        {
            "studyId": 191,
            "siteRecid": 1,
            "siteId": "10000"
        },
        {
            "studyId": 191,
            "siteRecid": 16521,
            "siteId": "11001"
        },
        {
            "studyId": 191,
            "siteRecid": 16632,
            "siteId": "11011"
        },
        {
            "studyId": 191,
            "siteRecid": 201,
            "siteId": "20000"
        }
    ],
    "subjects": [],
    "visits": [],
    "sftpLocations": [],
    "dicomLocations": [],
    "fileSystemLocations": [],
    "rawFileSystemLocations": [],
    "states": [],
    "modalities": [],
    "examDates": [],
    "series": [],
    "transferType": null,
    "customFolder": false,
    "customFile": false,
    "folderStructure": null,
    "fileStructure": null,
    "allSites": false,
    "allSubjects": false,
    "allVisits": false,
    "allStates": false,
    "allExamDates": false,
    "allModalities": false,
    "allSeries": false,
    "softEditOverride": false,
    "includePS": false,
    "includeSR": false,
    "includeRTStruct": false,
    "dicomTemplate": null,
    "errorMessage": null,
    "successMessage": null
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add [JMESPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) to your sampler and configure it:

- JMESPath expressions: sites[*].studyId
- Match No.: 0
- Default Values: STUDYID_NOT_FOUND

JMESPath Extractor will collect all the studyId values and return one selected randomly.